# jquery mobile and two different jquery versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, conflicting-libraries

I have specific task of having jquery and custom javascript inserted in DOM of existing page.

JQuery is inserted right before my script, and in mine script im using `window['my$'] = jQuery.noConflict(true);`.

This worked great when plugins were modified to bind on 'my$' version of jquery, without any conflict. Of course i had to modify plugins manually.

Problem came up when i had to bind jQuery mobile to my jQuery version. I tried 3 approaches and none of them worked correctly:

1. wrapping up whole jquery mobile into function, and inside function $ and jQuery are declared as `my$` variable:

   ```
   var jQuery = my$;

   var $ = my$
   ```
2. i tried preserving original jQuery

   ```
   my$.holdReady(true);

   $_old = $;

   $ = my$;

   jQuery = my$;

   //code for adding jquery mobile

   jQuery = $_old;

   $ = $_old;

   my$.holdReady(false);
   ```
3. Replacing all jQuery in jQuery mobile with `my$`

Any elegant solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

can you please write your all custom jQuery code between below function, using this code you don't need any no.conflict jquery

```
(function($) {

})(jQuery);
```